# Magento 2 - no css after pub folder has been deleted

Tags: magento2, error, deploy

I deleted the pub folder of my magento installation.
Then I used

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and now the site has no CSS at all.
How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please upload pub folder files from fresh setup and run above command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't delete the entire `pub` folder. Delete `pub/static/*` if/when needed.

You are most likely missing three critical files that will not be automatically regenerated:

```
pub/.htaccess 
pub/media/.htaccess  
pub/static/.htaccess
```

If you have a backup or a local dev site, I suggest finding and restoring them from there. Otherwise, you can find them in the appropriate branch of the Magento github repository (depending on what version you are running): https://github.com/magento/magento2

Comment: thanks saviour :)

Answer (score 3):

Well if you have deleted pub folder then even though you run

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

It will still not generate, because if its pub/static then it will generate automatically.

So better to create **pub directory** manually again

Then upload **media folder** in it from your backend.

Then run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

It will generate static folder again and css is also load back again !!